# Find and replace text in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-contacts

I have a string of data in one cell:

> "Membership and Volunteer Crew - do you like getting to know lots of new people? | Sauna Crew - Spend time sweating and supervising our sauna activity. | Crafters Crew - find and invite and present regional Crafts People at R&S and help them present workshops to our audience."

I need it to become:

> "Membership and Volunteer Crew ::: Sauna Crew ::: Crafters Crew"
>   in another cell on another sheet.

Trying to figure out how best to say please replace everything between '-' and '|' with ":::"

I am trying to create a Google Contact Group import friendly list.

Comment: Is this a one-off exercise, or do you need a repeatable solution?

Comment: Here a similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411105/google-sheets-multiple-search-and-replace-from-a-list or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753930/how-can-i-use-regexextract-function-in-google-docs-spreadsheets-to-get-all-occ which  might get you with some idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for [regexreplace](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en).

Suppose A1 contains the text

> Membership and Volunteer Crew - do you like getting to know lots of new people? | Sauna Crew - Spend time sweating and supervising our sauna activity. | Crafters Crew - find and invite and present regional Crafts People at R&S and help them present workshops to our audience.

Put the following in another cell

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"-[^|]*\|",":::")," - .*$","")
```

The result is

> Membership and Volunteer Crew ::: Sauna Crew ::: Crafters Crew

The first application of regexreplace deals with text between - and |, replacing it by :::. The second one trims the end (from " - " to the end of the string), since you do not have | at the end of the original string.

Comment: This solution is ideal.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Surely CTRL + F works.
Find and replace.

Search for - replace with :::
Search for | replace with :::

alternatively a formula would work.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",":::")

=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",":::")
```

The first replaces the -
The second replaces any |
IT assumes your data is in A1 and can be dragged down

Comment: But this doesn't leave: `Membership and Volunteer Crew ::: Sauna Crew ::: Crafters Crew`, it only replaces the `-|` for `:::`.